# Raise exception in Javascript via COM

Tags: javascript, exception, com

I have an COM object for consumption from JavaScript. I want to raise Error ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dww52sbt%28v=vs.94%29.aspx), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)) exceptions from COM to JavaScript. There is no documentation for it, hopefully there might be a convenient HRESULT.

Comment: Any error `HRESULT` will be reported to JavaScript in the form of an exception. If you want to provide additional information about the error, see [Returning Error Information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221062.aspx)

Comment: Looks promising. Hope this is what I was looking for.